# Material React Table doesn't render Firebase Firestore array type

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, material-table, material-react-table

I am using [Material React Table](https://www.material-react-table.com/) for a datatable, that displays a Firestore collection.  The Material React Table works perfectly, everything except for the one Array field.  Here is an example of a react object {docs} that shows the Array field, in my case called searcharray.  The other fields are strings and numbers.
[image: {docs} return from Firebase Firestore]

When the react data object is fed to Material React Table, via data={docs}, the column for searcharray looks compressed like this, notice all the words have been squished to a single string:
 
[image: material react table example]

My question, is there something here in the column setting that would separate the array values so they are searchable?

```js
{
  accessorKey: "searcharray",
  header: "searcharray",
},
```

I have read through the documentation from https://www.material-react-table.com/ and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: can you share the code snippet with snapshot of your document and if possible reproducible steps so it can be solved with recreation ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by creating a newArray, and using .join() on the internal array (searcharray), which replaces it with a string. So newArray can now be used as the feeder to the React Material Table data={newArray), and the searcharray column is searchable, with words separated.

```
const newArray = docs.map((obj) => {
    obj.searcharray = obj.searcharray.join();
    return obj;
});
```